# Convergence of $ \int\limits_{0}^1 f(tx)t^{-1}dt$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $f   \in C ^\infty (\mathbb{R})$.

Why this is true :

If f(tx) vanishes for t= 0, then, $F(f)= \int\limits_{0}^1 f(tx)t^{-1}dt$, is well defined .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119235/discussion-on-question-by-asma-convergence-of-int-limits-01-ftxt-1dt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is infinitely differentiable, it is Lipschitz (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity for why this holds). So in particular, we have the estimate $|f(tx)| \leq K|tx|$, where $K$ is the Lipschitz constant. This is enough to show integrability, since $$\int_0^1 |f(tx)| |t^{-1}|dt \leq K\int_0^1 |tx| |t^{-1}| dt = K |x| < \infty.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, but could you please point out where did  you use the assumption that f(tx) vanishes for t= 0 ?

Comment: For a Lipschitz function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have that for any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq K |x_1-x_2|$. In particular, taking $x_1 = tx$, $x_2 = 0$, we get $|f(tx)|\leq K|tx|$ from the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but this is true even if f(tx) does not vanishe when t= 0 , isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think so because $\frac{1}{t}$ doesn't converge

Comment: @asma No it is no true what you say. To give a counterexample, consider the constant function $f(x) = 1$. This function does not vanish at 0 and the integral doesn't converge either. So, you really need the assumption that f vanishes at 0. To be more explicit, I use $|f(tx)-f(0)| \leq K |tx-0| = |tx|$. In the assumptions, you state that $f(0) = 0$, so we see that $|f(tx)| \leq K |tx|$.

Comment: Ok I see,  thank you so much for your help